# Prove $\ell^5$ is contained in $\ell^6$.

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am struggling with the proof to show that, for any $p$, $r$ such that  $1 \le p <r < \infty$, that $\ell^ p\subset\ell ^r$.

Could somebody please give a helpful nudge by showing how this works for a specific case, for example, prove that $\ell^5 \subset\ell^6$ ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $p,q$ such as $1\leq p<q$ and $x = \{x_k\} \in l^p$. Then by definition $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {|x_k|^p} < \infty$.

Therefore $|x_k| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$.

This implies that there exists an index $k_0$ such that $|x_k| < 1$ for any $k ≥ k_0$.
So for $k ≥ k_0$ we have $|x_k|^q < |x_k|^p$ which implies $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {|x_k|^q} < \infty$  thanks to the comparison test for series.

Thus $x \in l^q$ and therefore $l^p\subset l^q$

---

Now, that is the proof. In order to help you grasp it, as you ask, lets say $p=5, q=10$ and $x = \{ \frac{1}{n^{1/20}}\}$ .

Lets see what happens: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x_k|^p} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\frac{1}{n^{1/20}}|^5} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\frac{1}{n^{1/4}}|} $

And $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|x_k|^q} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\frac{1}{n^{1/20}}|^{10}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\frac{1}{n^{1/2}}|} $

Now, we can see that from a point on (in this case $n=2$), $\frac{1}{n}<1$ and $\frac{1}{n}^{1/2}<\frac{1}{n}^{1/4}$  for all $n\geq 2$. That means that the second series is less than, or equal to the first. And if the first one converges, then so does the second one.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you so much. Can't believe how painfully simple this was!

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** use the Holder inequality.

Comment: Okay, I think I might have it, does this make sense?

 ![solution][1]


  [1]: http://tinypic.com/r/14jrkhe/8

Comment: please edit your question. I have trouble reading this.

Comment: Apologies I'll write it up in $\LaTeX$ now.

Comment: Consider an arbitrary $x \in$ $l^p$.
Therefore, $(||x||_p)^p$ < $M$ for some $M$ > 0.

To show $x$ belongs to $l^r$ we will show that $(||x||_r)^r$ < $N$ for some $N$ > 0.

$(||x||_r)^r$ = $\sum$$|x_k|^r$   =  $\sum$$|x_k|^{r-p}$$|x_k|^p$

$\leq$ $(||x||_p)^{r-p}$$(||x||_p)^p$   =  $((||x||_p)^p)^{r/p}$

< $(M)^{r/p}$

Thus $x$ is in $l^r$

Comment: to what elements do you apply the inequality?

Comment: I apply it to each one in turn. So,

$\sum |x_k|^{r-p} |x_k|^p$  $\leq$ $\sum (||x||_p)^{r-p} |x_k|^p$  $\leq$    $(||x||_p)^{r-p}$$(||x||_p)^p$

Comment: I don't think this is correct...

Comment: Yeah, reading it back I'm not sure why I was so convinced I was right at the time...
Could you perhaps give a push in the right direction?

Comment: actually it seems to be wrong. with $x_n = \frac 1{n^{1/5}}$ you have $x\in\ell^6$ but $x\notin \ell^5$.

Comment: the holder inequality proves that $L^p\subset L^r$ on $U$ as soon as $|U|<\infty$

Comment: 5 users find this answer useful. I have no idea how it can lead to a solution.